# How can I access second (or even third) level attributes in a vector layer and add them to the attribute table?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, dxf

I got some .dxf file containing buildings I need for my map. The file loads nicely into QGIS and I converted sucessfully to shape. I still can find the Information I need (the buildings height) in the element identify box. However, it is organized as some kind of second level attribute and I'm running out of ideas how to access the information (screenshot below).

[image: Object Identifier box showing how the attributes are organized]

In this example the only entry in the attribute table is "myid".

How can I access second (or even third) level attributes in a vector layer and add them to the attribute table, so I can work with them?

EDIT: The structure with the sub attributes (a... and (A... already exists in the .dxf.

EDIT2: The Attribute table currently only consists of one single field named "myid".
[image: AttributeTable]

EDIT3: Hm… The categorys (a… and (A… are shown in the Identify box when querying the .dxf. This is what I wanted to say. But of course, you may be right…
[image: Identify results for the original .dxf]

If this is rather the perimiter than a height field, it is useless to me anyway. Bad luck. Do you by any means know of a better way to convert .dxf to .shp creating a height field?

Comment: How did you create the Shapefile from DXF?

Comment: I used the Dxf2Shp converter plugin with the setting "Polygone".

Comment: What does your attribute table look like right now?

Comment: It looks to me as if the (a... is the trimmed word (abgeleitet) and (A... the trimmed word (Aktionen). Therefore I would be surprised if they would already be attributes in the original DXF data.

10.960m would be the perimeter and not the building height as far as I can tell.

This seems to be an import/conversion problem and your attributes not present in the shp.

Comment: I don't know how to convert this properly. I would adjust this question (including the title) to actually represent the problem you are facing or close it and ask a new question. (btw: I don't get a notification when you edit the question, so you better write answers as a comment as well)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, this is not related to the question I asked in the first place. What I had in mind will not work.

I opened [a new question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/79666/how-do-i-convert-a-dxf-to-a-shp-containing-a-field-with-height-information-in) and asked again. Thank you! Also thanks for the hint with the comments!

EDIT: I will accept this answer to close the topic in 5 hours…