# Converting a .dxf to a .shp containing a field with height information in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, convert, 3d, dxf

I received two .dxf for my project that represent my area of interest: one of them contains buildings, the other one terrain elevation (they both are 3D). I can successfully convert them to shapefiles using the **Dxf2Shp** plugin. They also display nicely compare to sample below:

[image: sample of my model area]

However, I loose the height information if I do so. The only field I get in the attribute table is "myid", that simply counts the polygons. 
Is there a way to convert the files to .shp creating a height field in the attribute tables, that takes the z values from the .dxf? This would already be fine, as the projection is metric.

Comment: In my experience it could be real tricky to get elevation data out from CAD. My solution is to convert contours (or other data) to a DEM in CAD and then export it to a GeoTiff. See [this](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75135/how-can-i-export-elevations-from-autocad-in-a-format-that-arcmap-can-read) question for tips on that process.

Comment: The problem with that would be, that I don have AutoCAD. I only have QGIS…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the GRASS command  [v.in.dxf](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/v.in.dxf.html) in Processing or in the Grass plugin (look at [GRASS GIS: import DXF](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Import_DXF)).

[image]

#### Some results in GRASS GIS with 3D dxf files:

- from [Vector support in GRASS GIS](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass63/screenshots/vector.php): Möbius strip visualization to show the 3D vector capabilities of GRASS 6 - imported from 3D DXF (screenshot: M. Neteler)

[image]

- or geological layers (3D dxf) (my work from [Grass Gis et Paraview: la modélisation géologique 3D pour les démunis, ou les enthousiastes...](https://web.archive.org/web/20190412055804/http://www.portailsig.org/content/grass-gis-et-paraview-la-modelisation-geologique-3d-pour-les-demunis-ou-les-enthousiastes))

[image]

The problem is that there is no support for 3D in QGIS: you must use Python with a module that support 3D (ogr or shapely), look at [QGIS user: Using/visualizing 3D data (Z values)](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Re-Qgis-user-Using-visualizing-3D-data-Z-values-td5004272.html) and [QGIS user: visualizing 3D data (Z values) or data with z attribute: a solution](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/visualizing-3D-data-Z-values-or-data-with-z-attribute-a-solution-td5005360.html) or use the commands of GRASS GIS.

Comment: I was not totally successful by now, but I think the supposed method will work. I have to learn working with GRASS GIS now. I only used it as a plugin for QGIS in the past, but it seems to provide some functions qGIS can't offer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since 2.14 Qgis supports 3d features. After importing DXF you can add height field with `field calculator` using expression:

> z($geometry)

or

> geom_to_wkt($geometry)

to get Well-Known Text (WKT) representation of the geometry.